# How can I pass multiple variables from view to controller using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am taking input from a form in view which is shown after selecting one of the options of a dropdown list.
[image: adding marks]
In controller I am sending to the model where the loop repeats the number of times fields are in the below form.
I just want to insert one record against each student. But since it sends data multiple times to controller it losses the values and is giving me database error
Also

```
<div class="card mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">
          Set Marks for <b><?php echo $student_name?></b>
          </div>

            <div class="card-body" >
                <form>
                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="oldPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Select Term</label>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select id="exam_term" class="form-control" name="exam_term" >
                                <option value="">Exam</option>
                                <option value="1">First Term  </option>
                                <option value="2">Second Term</option>
                            </select>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('old_pass')?></span>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>




            <div  id="formative_marks" style = "display:none" class="card mb-3">
              <div class="card-header">
                Summative Marks
              </div>
                  <?php

                    if($this->session->flashdata('message')){
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
                              '.$message.'</div>';
                    }
                    ?>
                <div class="card-body">

                 <form action="">

                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="oldPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Discipline</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <select id="disc" class="form-control" name="disc" >
                                <option value="">Grade</option>
                                <option value="1">A+</option>
                                <option value="2">A</option>
                                <option value="3">B+</option>
                                <option value="4">B</option>
                                <option value="5">C</option>
                                <option value="6">D</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('disc')?></span>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="newPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Practicals</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                          <select id="prac" class="form-control" name="prac" >
                                <option value="">Grade</option>
                                <option value="1">A+</option>
                                <option value="2">A</option>
                                <option value="3">B+</option>
                                <option value="4">B</option>
                                <option value="5">C</option>
                                <option value="6">D</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('new_pass')?></span>
                     </div>

                      <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="passConf" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Presentations</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="pres" class="form-control" name="pres" >
                                <option value="">Grade</option>
                                <option value="1">A+</option>
                                <option value="2">A</option>
                                <option value="3">B+</option>
                                <option value="4">B</option>
                                <option value="5">C</option>
                                <option value="6">D</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('pass_conf')?></span>
                     </div>  

                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="passConf" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Assignments</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="assi" class="form-control" name="assign" >
                                <option value="">Grade</option>
                                <option value="1">A+</option>
                                <option value="2">A</option>
                                <option value="3">B+</option>
                                <option value="4">B</option>
                                <option value="5">C</option>
                                <option value="6">D</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('pass_conf')?></span>
                     </div>   

                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="passConf" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Communication Skills</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="coms" class="form-control" name="coms" >
                                <option value="">Grade</option>
                                <option value="1">A+</option>
                                <option value="2">A</option>
                                <option value="3">B+</option>
                                <option value="4">B</option>
                                <option value="5">C</option>
                                <option value="6">D</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('pass_conf')?></span>
                     </div> 

                     <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <button type="button" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Save Grades</button>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('pass_conf')?></span>
                     </div>


                    </form>
                    </div>


            </div>

<script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('select').change(function(){
                    var exam_term = $('#exam_term option:selected').text();
                $('#formative_marks').show(1000);

                $('#submit_btn').click(function(){
                                        var form_data = {
                        disc : $('#disc option:selected').val(), 
                        prac : $('#prac option:selected').val(),
                        assi : $('#assi option:selected').val(),
                        coms : $('#coms option:selected').val(), 
                        pres : $('#pres option:selected').val(),
                        exam_term : exam_term,
                        student_id : <?php echo $student_id?>,
                        class_id   : <?php echo $class_id?>,
                        subject_id : <?php echo $subject_id?>,
                        ajax : '1'
                    };

                        $.ajax({
                         type:'ajax',
                         url:'<?= base_url()?>index.php/teacher/set_formative_marks',
                         method: 'post',
                         data : {form_data:form_data},
                         success: function(form_data){

                                    alert (response);
                                    }


                        });


                });


            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: If you have multi input fields, you can use class instead of id, then using jquery to select all elements have that class, then take the data and put it into array, submit to backend, backend will read the data as array, Could you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. trying to do this.

Comment: var options = $('.options').val(); I converted all ids to class with name options. How to change them to array

Comment: success: function(response) {  if you want get anything from alert(response)

Comment: type: "ajax" is incorrect.   Available values GET, POST, PUT (default: GET)

Comment: what is the database error you are getting?

Comment: It is inserting table values 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of syntax errors in your code.   Here is a little snippet I use when $.ajaxing .   I would suggest integrating this code (you can strip the request queue stuff if you want), then if you are still having problems and/or getting "database errors", go ahead and update your question to include the specific error you are getting from the database.

If you are having problems with maintaining state (and are losing pieces of data), perhaps store those in hidden inputs or using the "data" attribute (see jquery $.data).

Let me know if this makes sense and good luck.  :)

```
//Set this var to max requests in queue.
var ajaxMax = 5;

var ajaxActive = 0;
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  ajaxActive++;
  document.ajaxRunning = ajaxActive > 0;
  document.ajaxQueueFull = ajaxActive > ajaxMax;
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  ajaxActive--;
  document.ajaxRunning = ajaxActive > 0;
  document.ajaxQueueFull = ajaxActive > ajaxMax;
}

var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    data: myDataObj,
    success: function(result){}
});

while(request === null && (request.readyState < 1 || request.readyState > 4)) {
    if (document.ajaxQueueFull) {
      //abort existing requests
      $.each(request as v) {
         v.abort();
      }
    }
    pendingAjax.push(request);
}


$.when.apply($, pendingAjax).done( successCallback ).fail( failCallback)
```

Comment: I am giving my form class=formative_class and the in jquery btn click method I am making variables like this`code` var form_data = {
      disc : $('#disc option:selected').val(), 
      prac : $('#prac option:selected').val(),
      assi : $('#assi option:selected').val(),
      coms : $('#coms option:selected').val(), 
      pres : $('#pres option:selected').val(),
      exam_term : exam_term,
      student_id : <?php echo $student_id?>,
      class_id   : <?php echo $class_id?>,
      subject_id : <?php echo $subject_id?>,
     };